# Want to remove duplicate headers which I am reading from my csv file, but duplicate values do need to be written to csv

Tags: python

Suppose, this is a csv file that I'm reading:

```
header1, header2, header3
1,2,3
1,2,3
header1, header2, header3
4,5,6
4,5,6
header1, header2, header3
7,8,9
7,8,9
```

This is what I have tried. It might not be remotely right, but I'm very new to python.

```
with open("D:\\Python\\Python_Assignments\\DummyDuplicatesCheck\\dummyWithDuplicates.csv","r") as inputfile, open("D:\\Python\\Python_Assignments\\DummyDuplicatesCheck\\dummyWithoutDuplicates.csv","w") as outputfile:

 for row in input:
  print(row)
  if(row[0]!="header1" and row[1]!="header2" and row[2]!="header3"):
   output.write(row)
```

Expected output csv file :

```
header1, header2, header3
1,2,3
1,2,3
4,5,6
4,5,6
7,8,9
7,8,9
```

Basically, there shouldn't be any duplicate headers, but duplicate values should be printed

Comment: your code is wrong. But also using different variables for `inputfile` vs `input`. Also don't use `input`, as it's the builtin for interactive input

Answer (score 2):

First note that the filehandle => csv object seems to be missing from your example, so your code seems to compare *characters* from file instead. Seems that you're missing a step which is to instanciate `csv.reader` & `csv.writer` objects.

When you read a file line by line and you check `row[0]!="header1" and row[1]!="header2" and row[2]!="header3"`, it cannot work because `row[0] == 'h'`, `row[1] == 'e'` and so on...

Using `csv` module, I would read the title line separately using manual iteration on the csv object. Then I would write to output only if it's different.

Like this:

```
import csv

with open("input.csv","r") as inputfile, open("output.csv","w",newline="") as outputfile:
   csv_in = csv.reader(inputfile)
   csv_out = csv.writer(outputfile)
   title = next(csv_in)
   csv_out.writerow(title)
   for row in csv_in:
        if row != title:
             csv_out.writerow(row)
```

or with `writerows`

```
   csv_out.writerows(row for row in csv_in if row != title)
```

Comment: Not busy on moderating :P how come you're answering :P

Comment: you have to keep in touch with the real world sometimes.

Comment: This won't ever print the title, I think you should add `csv_out.writerow(title)` before the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks, edited. Promise next time I'll test my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
with open("src.csv","r") as inputfile, open("out.csv","w") as outputfile:
    lines = inputfile.readlines()
    outputfile.write(lines[0])
    for i in range(1, len(lines)):
        if lines[i] != lines[0]:
            outputfile.write(lines[i])
```

Comment: Nice and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a flag.

```
print_headers = True    
with open("D:\\Python\\Python_Assignments\\DummyDuplicatesCheck\\dummyWithDuplicates.csv","r") as inputfile, open("D:\\Python\\Python_Assignments\\DummyDuplicatesCheck\\dummyWithoutDuplicates.csv","w") as outputfile:
    input = inputfile.readlines()
    for row in input:
        if row[0]=="header1" and row[1]=="header2" and row[2]=="header3":
            if print_headers:
                outputfile.write(row)
                print_headers = False
        else:
            outputfile.write(row)
```